# Add or change class of elements based on hour of the day

Tags: javascript

I have a nice digital clock running with cobbled javascript. What I would like to add is 24 elements each with individual IDs, and have them change background-color to indicate hours of the day that have passed. 6 AM? Elements with IDs d1 through d6 are orange, the rest are white — and so on.

I've tried to fiddle with code that I've found that changes  attributes and other sort-of similar function code, but it all seems way off so I won't confuse you with it here!

Here's my current, working clock javascript:

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(n) {
  for (var r = this.toString(); r.length < n; r = 0 + r);
  return r;
};

function updateClock() {
  var now = new Date();
  var milli = now.getMilliseconds(),
    sec = now.getSeconds(),
    min = now.getMinutes(),
    hou = now.getHours(),
    mo = now.getMonth(),
    dy = now.getDate(),
    day = now.getDay(),
    yr = now.getFullYear();
  var months = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
      var days = ['SUNDAY', 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY'];

  var tags = ["mon", "d", "y", "h", "m", "s", "mi", "day"],
    corr = [months[mo], dy, yr, hou.pad(2), min.pad(2), sec.pad(2), milli. pad(3), days[day]];
  for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++)
    document.getElementById(tags[i]).firstChild.nodeValue = corr[i];
    
    if(hou < 12){var ampm = "MORNING"}
        if(hou >= 12 && hou <= 18){var ampm = "AFTERNOON"}
        if(hou > 18){var ampm = "EVENING"}
document.getElementById("ampm").innerHTML = ampm;
}

function initClock() {
  updateClock();
  window.setInterval("updateClock()", 1);
}
```

The part of the html I want to affect:

```
<body onLoad="initClock()" style="background-color: #000000;">
<div class="dots" id="d1"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d2"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d3"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d4"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d5"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d6"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d7"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d8"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d9"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d10"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d11"></div>
<div class="dots" id="d12"></div>
etc...
```

And the relevant css lines (though .dots styling will change, this was just a test), assuming I'd be switching or adding a class of each element as time passes.

```
.dots{
    width:20px; height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}
.past{
    background-color: white;
}
.future{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Sorry for the code-amateur question. Oh how I've tried to figure this out myself...

Thank you!

Comment: Never pass a string to `setInterval` pass a function `window.setInterval(updateClock, 1);`

Comment: @nobi-wan You should paste entire code, if you want anyone to help you. HTML code is missing and your code doesn't work.

Comment: @ulou Here's the beta of the (working) clock: http://levelmag.com/clock — I intend to patch the svg to bin the barcode and replace it with the 24 ID'd elements.